# file upload using drag drop

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I want to upload and download files using drag n drop between user computer and web browser. How can I do it ASP.NET/AJAX or JS/JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also see http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/html5-drag-and-drop-and-file-api-tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)